# Wordpress get data from url

Tags: wordpress, url, http-get

I am trying to get data (data) from the following URL.

http://www.example.dk/page/?data=1

I use the following code for getting the data to the wordpress page:

```
<?php $_GET['data']; ?>
```

But I don't get the data to the page. Isn't it the normal way to get data from URL with php?

Comment: Did you mean to `echo` the result there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt pointed out, you'll need to `echo` the the result. Like:

```
<?php echo $_GET['data']; ?>
```

If your server is setup to use PHP shorthand statements you might also be able to use

```
<?= $_GET['data'] ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that might be the solution. Thou, when I see my code in a browser my looks like: <!--?php echo $_GET['data']; ?--> instead of <?php echo $_GET['data']; ?>  ? Is wordpress doing something with ?> ?

Comment: Found out that you cannot write php directly into a wordpress post. So I installed a plugin that could handle it. The following code works perfectly: <?php echo $_GET['data']; ?>

Comment: Ah, that would have been helpful to post in the question. Glad you got it figured out.